# LocalDateTime extension functions and smart casting

Tags: kotlin

I tried and failed (or partially succeeded) to implement extension functions for `LocalDateTime`

here is my attempt:

```
fun LocalDateTime.isNotBefore(other: ChronoLocalDateTime<*>) = !isBefore(other)
```

The problem is that IntelliJ complains that it cannot smartcast my `curTime`variable (which is a `val` and `LocalDateTime?`)

`isNotBefore(curTime)` will have a red squiggly line and complain that it can't smartcast it. So I must use `!!`

don't worry if you can't replicate it, I have a lot of code - these are the important parts.

The difference is that a regular `LocalDateTime` method like `isBefore()` does not need the smartcast in this spot.

So this means I didn't implement something correctly in my extension function.

Does anyone know how I can fix the extension function so that I don't need to use `!!`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a closer look at the `isBefore` signature, it expects `ChronoLocalDateTime<*>!` type. This is kotlin notation for a [Platform Type](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#notation-for-platform-types). Exclamation mark means it expects either `ChronoLocalDateTime<*>` or `ChronoLocalDateTime<*>?` while your `isNotBefore` method expects non nullable type.

If you change your extension function to accept nullable it will work the same way.

```
fun LocalDateTime.isNotBefore(other: ChronoLocalDateTime<*>?) = !isBefore(other)
```

Comment: great, I was trying to do that but gave up because I didn't know the notation (also I was having trouble searching for an `!` in google :)